# Header Logo has Gone off Center

Tags: css

I did a wordpress site a while ago. I just a had a look at it today and the logo has travelled east for some reason. It've tired clearfix's floats, text-align, and margin: 0 auto. Can anyone enllighten me to what has happened, or how it can be fixed? http://www.mallorymcgough.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a minus margin property on the `.header-social` element remove it and the logo will snap back to the middle

```
  #wrapper .header-social {
        margin-bottom: -44px;
  }
```

Comment: It's better to remove the target the exact element (`.header-info`) and remove the value that's causing the issue.

Comment: True but the header is not exactly in the middle he will have to make a few modifications to that. unless he removes the margin like this

Comment: Although this moves the logo, it pushes it to the left.

Answer (score 1):

The `.header-info` element, which contains the phone number above the logo is displacing the logo.

A quick way to fix this is to give it absolute positioning.

```
.header-info { position: absolute; }
```

### Edited below: alternate solution

A better fix is to reduce the `line-height` of the element, as declared on `style.css:4062`

```
.header-social .header-info, .header-social .top-menu {
    line-height: 43px;
}
```

Reduce this number to a smaller line height and the issue will be gone.